# Browsing the answers by deleted users

Tags: support, answers, deleted-accounts

Over the lifetime of the site, several [high profile users](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/154922/top-deleted-users) had their profiles deleted (two such deletions were recently discussed on meta). As a result,  [over 8000 answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/156010/all-answers-by-deleted-users), many of them valuable, are  less visible now than they were when  the author's profile existed. Concerns were raised on meta over not being able to see "posts neatly available in one place".

> Is there a way to browse the answers posted by deleted users?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a project that has been abandoned. The thread contains nothing but a broken link.

Comment: One can use the SEDE query [Get all answers by a deleted user, together with questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/112470/get-all-answers-by-a-deleted-user-together-with-questions) instead.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. I put together the page [Answers by deleted Math.SE users](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29863189/mse/deleted.html) which organizers the answers by score, by user and by tags. How it works:

- Deleted users are listed in the decreasing order of the total score of their posts.
- Tags are listed alphabetically, with answer counts in parentheses (the tag counts are for all deleted users together).
- Answers are listed in the decreasing order of their score. Negatively scored answers (as of the time of database dump) are omitted.
- All content remains within Math.SE; the page only links to it.

Technical notes:

- The page loads a large JavaScript file (over 1 MB), since unlike  SE, it does not have an SQL server behind it.
- If anyone wants to mirror or improve the page and script, [zip archive](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29863189/mse/deleted.zip) is available.